# Why execution plan from a remote server on the same postgres database differs?

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I have two postgres servers with the same IP and different ports (the same machine).
I use postgres_fdw to link the databases - foreign tables from the remote database are visible in schema 'eaps'.

Query to join 5 tables:
Tables:
e_connector :

```
         |eap_id|start_object_id|end_object_id|skompo|ekompo|connector_type|
```

..
I need to scan the table with filter on (eap_in,skompo,ekompo) and then join tables e_object and c_package_tree to obtain additional data from them for start_object_id and end_object_id.

e_object :

```
      |eap_id|object_id|package_id |name|
```

c_package_tree :

```
      |eap_id|package_id |nametree|
```

I need result:

```
Select 
  tc.connector_type,skompo as start_kompo,ekompo as end_kompo,
  ts.name as sname, trs.nametree as snametree,
  te.name as ename, tre.nametree as enametree
from 
 e_connector  tc, e_object ts, e_object te, 
 c_package_tree trs , c_package_tree tre 
where 
    tc.eap_id=36 and 'OU' in (skompo,ekompo) and -- scan index
    tc.eap_id=ts.eap_id and tc.start_object_id=ts.object_id and -- with index
    tc.eap_id=te.eap_id and tc.end_object_id=te.object_id and -- with index
    tc.eap_id=trs.eap_id and ts.package_id=trs.package_id and -- with index
    tc.eap_id=tre.eap_id and te.package_id=tre.package_id  -- with index
```

The query must be changed to support first scan e_connector to prevent huge join on 4 other tables

```
with con as (
    Select eap_id,tc.connector_type,skompo as start_kompo,ekompo as end_kompo,
    start_object_id,end_object_id
    from e_connector tc
    where 
    tc.eap_id=36 and 'OU' in (skompo,ekompo) ) 
Select tc.connector_type,start_kompo,end_kompo,
    ts.name as sname, trs.nametree as snametree,
    te.name as ename, tre.nametree as enametree
    from con tc, e_object ts, e_object te, c_package_tree trs , c_package_tree tre 
    where 
    tc.eap_id=ts.eap_id and tc.start_object_id=ts.object_id and 
    tc.eap_id=te.eap_id and tc.end_object_id=te.object_id and
    tc.eap_id=trs.eap_id and ts.package_id=trs.package_id and
    tc.eap_id=tre.eap_id and te.package_id=tre.package_id
```

It takes 229msec on database and first scans e_connector index (eap_id,skompo,ekompo), makes Bitmap OR  and  makes nested loop inner joins to other tables.
The same query with 'eaps.' before tables' names, while executed on remote server to the same database has different execution plan on the same data.

e_connector has 1142600 records, 10500 while filtered
e_object  has 1504650 records, 63000 records for given eap_id and ~49800 of them have connections

Indexes:

```
Create unique index ie_object on e_object(eap_id,object_id);
Create unique index ic_package_tree on c_package_tree(eap_id,package_id);
Create index ix_connector_kompo on e_connector(eap_id,skompo,ekompo);
Create index ix_connector_start_end on e_connector(eap_id,start_object_id,end_object_id);
```

How can I avoid plan with :

```
 {
          "Node Type": "Foreign Scan",
          "Operation": "Select",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Startup Cost": 100,
          "Total Cost": 311.73,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 2088,
          "Output": [
            "ts.name",
            "ts.eap_id",
            "ts.object_id",
            "te.name",
            "te.eap_id",
            "te.object_id",
            "trs.nametree",
            "trs.eap_id",
            "tre.nametree",
            "tre.eap_id"
          ],
          "Relations": "(((eaps.e_object ts) 
          INNER JOIN (eaps.e_object te)) 
          INNER JOIN (eaps.c_package_tree trs)) 
          INNER JOIN (eaps.c_package_tree tre)",
          "Remote SQL": 
          "SELECT r2.name, r2.eap_id, r2.object_id, r3.name, r3.eap_id, r3.object_id, r4.nametree, r4.eap_id, r5.nametree, r5.eap_id 
          FROM (((public.e_object r2 
          INNER JOIN public.e_object r3 ON (((r2.eap_id = r3.eap_id)))) 
          INNER JOIN public.c_package_tree r4 ON (((r2.eap_id = r4.eap_id)) AND ((r2.package_id = r4.package_id)))) 
          INNER JOIN public.c_package_tree r5 ON (((r2.eap_id = r5.eap_id)) AND ((r3.package_id = r5.package_id))))"
        }
```

I need to join the result on remote server.

````
with con as (
    Select eap_id,tc.ea_guid,tc.connector_type,skompo as start_kompo,ekompo as end_kompo,
    start_object_id,end_object_id
    from e_connector tc
    where 
    tc.eap_id=36 and 'OU' in (skompo,ekompo) ) 
Select tc.ea_guid,tc.connector_type,  end_kompo,
    ts.object_type as stype,ts.name as sname, ts.ea_guid as start_guid,trs.nametree as snametree,
    te.object_type as etype,te.name as ename, te.ea_guid as end_guid,tre.nametree as enametree
    from con  tc 
    join  e_object ts on (tc.eap_id=ts.eap_id and tc.start_object_id=ts.object_id)
    join e_object te on (tc.eap_id=te.eap_id and tc.end_object_id=te.object_id)
    join c_package_tree trs on (tc.eap_id=trs.eap_id and ts.package_id=trs.package_id)
    join c_package_tree tre on (tc.eap_id=tre.eap_id and te.package_id=tre.package_id)```
with join syntax
````

Comment: `from 
 e_connector  tc, e_object ts, e_object te, 
 c_package_tree trs , c_package_tree tre ` <<-- Please use the JOIN syntax.

Comment: with use_remote_estimate=true as an option for foreign server postgresql makes different executtion plan - not the best but acceptable.

Comment: join syntax or where syntax - the same result in execution plan. Joins are simple eap_id&object_id on e_object and eap_id&package_id on c_package_tree. Version with more subqueries defined as with list to join table by table  doesn't  effect execution plan. My question is - why different plans. The same query with postgres_fdw option works fine, so the answer is - set use_remote-estimate, but still it is different plan than on database.